# find command not accepting -mmin option

Tags: find

I am trying to find all the file name starting with testing and the last modified date is 1 min ago, and move them to another folder, but i am getting the below error. I have tried -mtime +1 (but mtime is 1day ago, not my goal) and it is working fine, i wonder why -mmin is not working for my case? anyone can help?

```
bash-3.2$ find /testing/ -type f -name "testing.*" -mmin +1 -exec mv {} /temp/ \;
find: bad option -mmin
find [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Comment: Pretty sure its not supposed to have `+` before the number.

Comment: Also gonna assume you are on solaris as SunOs' find does not have that option.Try `/usr/xpg4/bin/find`

Comment: What is the Operating system you are using this find command?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with bash. `find` with the same parameters would behave the same no matter how you exec it.

Answer (score 0):

The command itself is just fine , what output you get if you run :

> find --version